# Stata replacing missing values as well when using operators

Tags: stata

I have a data set in which several observations have missing values, denoted by `.` (system missing).

For the observations that actually do have values, I want to make a dummy variable with the value `1` if the observations have a value; otherwise the dummy variable stays missing (I used `gen dummy = .`).

When I type `replace dummy = 1 if variable > 0` it does indeed replace the dummy with 1, but for some reason it does for every observation, also those with a missing value.

How do I only replace it for the values which have a non-missing value?

Comment: Off-topic here. Please see advice on software-specific questions in the Help Center. This is intelligible to any Stata programmer even without a explicit self-contained example, so I have voted for migration to Stack Overflow.

Comment: What do we use the stata tag for then?

Comment: We use the Stata tag when it is relevant, as flagging use of Stata code within a primarily statistical question. But the use of a tag is nothing much to do with whether a question is on-topic. A tag like `economics` would not mean, say, that a question purely about economics was on-topic here. https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic explains.

Comment: All right thank you I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Stata, missing has value equal to infinity.

Try: `replace dummy = 1 if variable !=.`

Comment: Infinity here means a very large positive value larger than any other value and dependent on variable type, although precisely what value is usually immaterial to user and programmer alike. For that reason, `variable < .` is idiomatic for `variable != .`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it and also helps me in future configurations!